# Prove that minimum of the matrix norm is achieved at certain parametres

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, self-learning

> Given matrix $A\in R^{n\times m}$ prove that minimum of the $||A-xy^T||$, $||B||=tr(B^TB)$, is achieved when $x$ is an eigenvector of $AA^T$, corresponding to its greatest eigenvalue, and $y$ is an eigenvector of $A^TA$, corresponding to its greatest eigenvalue.

Progress I've made so far:

$f(x,y)=||A-xy^T||=tr(A^TA-2A^Txy^T+yx^Txy^T)$,

$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=0 \Leftrightarrow tr(-2Ay+2xy^Ty)=0 \Leftrightarrow tr(xy^T)=tr(A)$

Comment: It's just a special case of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Basic_low-rank_approximation_problem).

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel with more clear formulation of  my problem I found your answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791877/minimizing-frobenius-norm-for-two-variables). So, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome! You can find [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759032/proof-of-eckart-young-mirsky-theorem) a proof of the general statement.